# Office js Dialog api 16.13 Word doesn't open dialog next time

Tags: ms-word, office-js

I have following code and it's being triggered form a task pane button:

```javascript
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(
  dialogUrl,
  {
    width: 60,
    height: 60,
    requireHTTPS: false,
    displayInIframe: false
  },
  asyncResult => {
    dialog = asyncResult.value;

    if (asyncResult.status === "failed") {
      dispatch(MessageActions.showError(asyncResult.error.message));
      dialog.close();
    } else {
      dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, arg => {
        dispatch({ type: LOADED });
        dialog.close();
      });
      dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogEventReceived, arg => {
        if (arg && arg.error === 12006) {
          dispatch({ type: LOADED });
        }
      });
    }
  }
);
```

Once I called this snippet I get an error

> Error code - 12007 .A dialog box is already opened from the task pane.
>   A task pane add-in can only have one dialog box open at a time.

but really it's not. For previous versions, it worked just fine. Is there anybody who knows what's happened or I might be doing now something wrong?

This is only reproducible on MacOs 10.13.4 and Word v16.13 (18.05.13). Word for 
Windows and Word Online work perfectly.

Comment: I don't have an answer but a side note: The "requreHTTPS" property of the options object is deprecated and has no effect.

Comment: @RickKirkham thanks man, removed already. :)

Comment: I'm getting this also - macOS 10.13.4 and Word 16.13.1 (180523).